# Function Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, function-and-relation-composition

How do I decompose a function when I'm given $f(g(x))$ and $f(x)$ and the required is $g(x)$?
I done some searching on Google and most sites demonstrate the solution where it's left open, they just give $f(g(x))$ and let you solve to whatever set of functions you get (because there are multiple sets of functions that satisfy the decomposition).

Example:
$(g \circ f)(x)= 3/x-2$

$f(x)= (x+1)/(x-2)$

$g(x)= ?$

Comment: Maybe provide an actual task/exercise that is troubling you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you let $h(x)$ be whatever expression you have on the right side, we have $f(g(x)) = (f \circ g)(x) = h(x)$, i.e., $f \circ g = h $. If $f$ is invertible, then we can write $g = f^{-1} \circ h$. Since $f$ is given, you can compute $f^{-1}$ by whatever means you already know.

But I think you meant examples like:

If $f(g(x)) = \sin{2x}$, and $f(x) = \sin{x}$, then $g(x) = 2x$, and so on. Always try to recognize operations like squaring, applying $\cos$ to something, taking logarithims, etc.

Comment: What you have told me is exactly like what I found on Google, they tell you to look for hints (squaring, square root, cos, sin, tan, log ...etc)
But isn't there a more direct (systematic) way of solving for $g(x)$ rather than looking for operations
Also, I added an example to the question if you can help me with it please

Comment: Well, first you should write $f(x)$ as $1 + \frac{3}{x -2}$. From here it should be clear that $g(x) = x - 1$, so that this $1$s cancel. Sometimes you have to do something to the expression, to leave it more recognizeable

Comment: thanks alot
I got mixed up a little with $f^{-1}$

but never mind, I figured it out